# Prevent overriding some property in application.properties - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I want to move some configuration in my property file, but don't want it to be overwritten at runtime, for security purpose. Is it possible to do it in spring boot?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, anything in secure.properties will not be able to be overridden as it will be added to the start of the env (from the properties file), regardless of what has been overridden.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurePropertiesConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void setConfigurableEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        try {
            final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("secure.properties");
            env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getFilename(), PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why having it both has field and as argument in the setter?  The field probably can be removed?

Comment: @KeesvanDieren yes, well spotted

Comment: This is being overwritten by the properties file of an active profile for me (Spring Boot 2.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the SecurePropertiesConfig method posted here and interestingly what is happening for me is the property value is different based on if I use a @Value annotation or just load the Environment. The @Value annotation is resolving before the setConfigurableEnvironment method resolves. So @Value will resolve to property file values set directly in the classpath while the Environment variable will have the secure (un-overridable) property value once the method is actually running. It works if I just use Environment, but unfortunately that makes it a bit brittle to a future code change accidentally using @Value instead, thinking it is "secure". I modified the SecurePropertiesConfig.java to be a ApplicationContextInitializer to force it to load the properties first.

SecureProperties.java

```
public class SecurePropertiesConfig implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        try {
            final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("secure.properties");
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getFilename(), PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

And then add the initializer in your application.properties:

```
context.initializer.classes=package.path.config.SecureProperties
```