# Spring Boot: Make property non-configurable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I have several options to [externalize my configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). However, how can I make such properties **non-configurable**, i.e. readonly.

Concretly, I want to set `server.tomcat.max-threads` to a fixed value and do not want somebody who is going to start the application to have the ability to change it. This could easily be done by passing it as a command line argument for instance.

It's probably not possible by default, maybe someone could suggest workarounds?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039289/prevent-overriding-some-property-in-application-properties-spring-boot/47040012#47040012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. Set `System.setProperty("prop", "value")` Property hard coded
2. Use properties that will override all other properties
3. Set system property hard coded

   ```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("server.tomcat.max-threads","200");
         SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
       }
   ```
4. Properties in `secure.properties` will override all others (see, [Prevent overriding some property in application.properties - Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039289/prevent-overriding-some-property-in-application-properties-spring-boot/47040012#47040012))

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class SecurePropertiesConfig {

   @Autowired
   private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

   @Autowired
   public void setConfigurableEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
     try {
       final Resource resource = new 
       ClassPathResource("secure.properties");
       env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new 
           PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getFilename(), 
           PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource)));
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing an `ApplicationContextInitializer` ([Docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)), which in its `initialize()` method simply sets the static value programatically:

```
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(MAX_THREADS, MAX_THREADS_VAL);
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("tomcatConfigProperties", props));

}
```

Another possible solution was found here: [Prevent overriding some property in application.properties - Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039289/prevent-overriding-some-property-in-application-properties-spring-boot/47040012#47040012)